# Rails, dynamically loop created mutli submission forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I am generating a table of users with a submit button at the end of each row, this displays all the users and their data correctly. However the submit button only submits the user_id of the last user displayed. I think this is because the submit button is tied to f.submit and f remains the same throughout all the iterations of the user table being displayed, as such only the last value assigned to f gets kept, how do I get around this?

Second question how do I add a checkbox system to this, so that I may submit an invite on all the users I have checked off? (And as such insert multiple rows into the database?)

```
<%= form_for @invite , :url => story_invites_path do |f| %>

<% @users = User.all %>
    <table>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <tr><td>
                <%= user.id %>

            </td><td>
                <%= user.email %>
            </td><td>
                <%= user.name %>

            </td><td>




                <%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => user.id %>


                <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
            </td></tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just figured out the first issue with my code, I needed to create a new form for every row that iterates, I called it "f2"

```
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= form_for @invite , :url => story_invites_path do |f2| %>

            <tr><td>
                <%= user.id %>

            </td><td>
                <%= user.email %>
            </td><td>
                <%= user.name %>

            </td><td>


            <%= f2.text_field :user_id, :value => user.id %>


            <%= f2.submit 'Send' %>
            </td></tr>
            <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

I still don't get the second part though